# Positive integers NOT divisible by 3 or more primes

Tags: combinatorics

How many positive integers $<200$ are NOT divisible by 3 or more primes ?

My answer:

\begin{eqnarray*}
&=&\text{Number of positive integers less than }200-\text{ Number of composite integers less than $200$ having at least 3 different prime factors}\\
&=&199-\Bigg(\left\lfloor\frac{199}{lcm(2,3,5)}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{199}{lcm(2,3,7)}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{199}{lcm(2,3,11)}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{199}{lcm(2,3,13)}\right\rfloor\\&&+\,\left\lfloor\frac{199}{lcm(2,3,17)}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{199}{lcm(2,3,19)}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{199}{lcm(2,3,23)}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{199}{lcm(2,3,29)}\right\rfloor\\&&+\,\left\lfloor\frac{199}{lcm(2,3,31)}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{199}{lcm(3,5,7)}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{199}{lcm(3,5,11)}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{199}{lcm(3,5,13)}\right\rfloor\Bigg)\\
&=&199-(6+4+3+2+8*1)\\
&=&199-23\\
&=&176
\end{eqnarray*}
I did NOT count composite integers having **more than** 3 different prime factors because i thought they should be multiples of composite integers having **exactly** 3 different prime factors and counting them would result in an overcount.

However, the answer given in the book is $168$.

What is wrong in my answer ?

Comment: You would have subtracted the ones divisible by four or more primes more than once.  The lowest such number is $210$, which is not in your range, but if it were you would have to add it back in once.  This is the [inclusion-exclusion principle]( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the multiples of $\operatorname{lcm}(2,5,7)$, $\operatorname{lcm}(2,5,11)$, $\operatorname{lcm}(2,5,13)$, $\operatorname{lcm}(2,5,17)$, $\operatorname{lcm}(2,5,19)$, $\operatorname{lcm}(2,7,11)$, and $\operatorname{lcm}(2,7,13)$, which make a difference of

$$1\cdot 2 + 6\cdot 1 = 8 = 176 - 168.$$

Comment: Yes, i missed those combinations.